# How to create an AWS IAM policy/role or whatever to allow import of an ova file

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm trying to import a VM created on VirtualBox. It was exported as an OVA file. I have gone to a number of forums to try to find out how to get around this error.

```
An error occurred (InvalidParameter) when calling the ImportImage operation: The service role <vmimport> does not exist or
 does not have sufficient permissions for the service to continue
```

I have used the console to instead of the aws-cli to perform the steps described here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmimport-image-import.html

However I am still getting the error. Can anyone guide me on how to troubleshoot?

The command to import looks like this;

```
aws ec2 import-image --description "Bitnami WordPress CiviCRM" --license-type BYOL --disk-containers file://containers.jso
n
```

My .aws/credentials and config files are set up correctly as I can perform other CLI functions but I am stumped on how to associate the vmimport role with the IAM user.

Comment: Check your IAM role to see if you have access, if not, add this particular role to your IAM role policy.

Comment: I've define the role vmimport. I have attached the role to the AWSImportExportFullAccess policy. That policy is attached to the group of which the IAM user is a member. I don't know what else to do

Comment: Do you have the access to put a role or create a role?

Comment: Does the IAM user have ec2:ImportImage permission?

Comment: The  policy AWSImportExportFullAccess is attached to the group assigned to the IAM user. Is ImportImage somewhere else?

Comment: Lingo Tang: I am the root user of the account

Comment: Is AWSImportExportFullAccess the only policy attached to the IAM user whose access keys you are using in CLI [it only permits "importexport:*" i.e. importexport APIs? If yes, then you need ec2:ImportImage permission, you can test it via AmazonEC2FullAccess policy.

Comment: Sudo: I am a bit lost here. Where is the ec2.ImportImage permission specified? I have searched around for it but don't find it. I'm a newbie at this so bear with me.

Comment: No worries :) So, you are using "aws ec2 import-image" command to import the image. So one of the requirement is that you should have necessary permission to complete the command. CLI/API details here.
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/import-image.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_ImportImage.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153301/discussion-between-sudo-and-vietyank).

Comment: I decided to delete everything and start over again and the import task was created, however, it failed with "ClientError: Unknown OS / Missing OS files."

Comment: I consider this issue closed but I don't know how to close it.  The other issue I will research and post later if I need to.

Comment: For the benefit of posterity, I was getting exactly the same "service role vmimport" error message described by OP and found the solution on this page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vm-import/latest/userguide/vmie_prereqs.html See the subsections entitled "Required Permissions for IAM Users" and especially "Required Service Role". Once I followed the steps described in those sections, I was able to import images via the aws cli.

Comment: @fd This like made it work for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Never be afraid to start over, which is what I did. I found another "cookbook" to do this and followed the instructions. I was able to import the image but the it did not convert. The message was "*ClientError: Unknown OS / Missing OS files*".

I'll submit another question on this if I can't figure it out.